# Exchange limit internal email limit UNLIMITED, Outgoing 1024kb Exchange 2007?

Tags: email, exchange-2007, email-server, outlook-2007

I want any file size sent amongst our company to each other to be unlimited. I want to restrict OUTBOUND email to people to 1mb. If anyone can help me with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to allow unlimited size on internal messages, you need to not put any limit (or set it high enough) in the various areas where you can set them in Exchange (global, per-user, on HT servers, on receive connectors, etc.).

In order to limit size for outgoing external messages, you need to set the limit on the send connector(s) you're using to deliver them.

Lots of great info [here](http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-2007/management-administration/exchange-2007-message-size-limits.html) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124345(EXCHG.80).aspx).

Comment: They are really good links and have helped in understanding. For example lets say I set the Internal Hub as 40mb and the external as 4MB but I want 1 user to have a 10MB limit externally? Thank you so much all for help.

Comment: You can't do that; if you set a limit on a connector, it will affect *any* message flowing through that connector. A message can hit various limits during its transit (global, per-server, per-connector, per-user, etc.), and the lowest one always prevails.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this limit is set on the Receive Connectors for whichever servers are in the Hub Transport role. The maximum value for that field is a hair under 2GB. While not unlimited, it's pretty darned high.

Receive Connectors on your Edge Servers are what limit inbound internet mail-sizes, the Receive Connectors on your Hub Transport servers are what limit internal mail-sizes.

Comment: So How can I limit outbound messages after the internal mail sizes are set?

Comment: There is another Receive Connector on your Edge servers that 'faces' your internal environment. The limit on that connector will limit our 'outbound' send-size.

Comment: Or you can set it on the Edge server *send* connector, which I think is better suited for this purpose.